# JavaScript, salvar os valores iniciais das variaveis

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Galera, eu to fazendo um pequeno codigo em *JS*, nele eu preciso salvar os valores iniciais do meu *html*. Eu tenho um campo paragrafo(`<p>`) que inicia de uma forma, eu queria salvar o estado inicial deste paragrafo para eu sempre comparar o estado atual com o estado inicial, mas por algum motivo isso não esta funcionando.

A linha de codigo do HTML:

```
<p class="cont" id="res">A soma dos primeiros <input id="cont" type="number" name="num" min="0" max="100000000"> multiplos de <input id="mul1" type="number" name="num" min="1" max="1000"> e <input id="mul2" type="number" name="num" min="1" max="1000"> é: </p>
```

Codigo JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //quando a janela carrega eu salvo o estado inicial do <p>
    var pad = document.getElementById("res");
    //funcao q faz o calculo
    document.getElementById("calcmult").onclick = function () {

        var contador = document.getElementById("cont").value;
        var num1 = document.getElementById("mul1").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("mul2").value;
        var i=0;
        var x=0;
        var y=0;
        while(i<=contador){
            if(x%num1 == 0 && x%num2 == 0){
                y = y + x;
                i++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        //defino que x é igual ao paragrafo
        x = document.getElementById("res");
        //o html de x é igual ao valor inicial do paragrafo + y que é o valor
        x.innerHTML = pad.innerHTML + y;
        //zero os valores que estavam nos campos
        document.getElementById("cont").value = '';
        document.getElementById("mul1").value = '';
        document.getElementById("mul2").value = '';
    }
}
```

Por algum motivo ele salva o estado inicial toda hora, fazendo com q o estado inicial mude e não fazendo o efeito que eu quero. Agora quando eu calculo ele, na segunda execução, concatena os valores de resposta ao invés de simplesmente comparar com o estado inicial, que ainda não tem resposta, e dar apenas um valor.

Meu objetivo final é, por exemplo, tenho o seguinte paragrafo:

> Digite o primeiro numero para somar o valor ________, digite o segundo ______, a soma é: *resultado*.

Eu quero que o resultado fique no mesmo paragrafo, eu sei que é mais facil criar outro paragrafo, mas eu queria fazer no mesmo por razões de desafio. Alguem sabe como resolver o meu problema? Obrigado

**Obs:** Essas imagens devem ajudar a entender melhor o problema:

Estado Inicial:

[image: Estado Inicial]

Depois de realizar um calculo:

[image: Depois de realizar um calculo]

Depois do segundo calculo, estado atual do codigo:

[image: Depois do segundo calculo, estado atual]

Segundo calculo, objetivo final:

[image: Segundo calculo objetivo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque está mexendo com objetos.

A linha

```
var pad = document.getElementById("res");
```

Não cria outro objeto, ela cria uma referência, na variável `pad` para o objeto que pode ser acessado por meio de `document.getElementById("res")`.

Para salvar uma cópia do objeto, use a função `cloneNode`, desta forma:

```
var pad = document.getElementById("res").cloneNode(true);
```

O parâmetro é para copiar todos os elementos filhos, caso existam. Esta função copia também o id, então, se for adicionar no mesmo documento, é recomendável mudar o id.

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: Aeee, deu certo! Obrigado mesmo, nos cursos que eu fiz (online) nenhum mostrou esse cloneNode, mas enfim obrigado! :3

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso? Observe o cast de Numer para String da variável y. Além do mais eu dou um replace no elemento p sempre que preciso atualiza-lo:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var pad = document.getElementById("res");
  document.getElementById("calcmult").onclick = function() {

    var contador = document.getElementById("cont").value;
    var num1 = document.getElementById("mul1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("mul2").value;
    
    var i = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    while (i <= contador && contador && num1 && num2) {
      if (x % num1 == 0 && x % num2 == 0) {
        y = y + x;
        i++;
      }
      x++;
    }


    var x = document.createElement("p");
    x.innerHTML = pad.innerHTML + " " + String(y);
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].replaceChild(x, pad);
    pad = x;

    //zero os valores que estavam nos campos
    document.getElementById("cont").value = '';
    document.getElementById("mul1").value = '';
    document.getElementById("mul2").value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="cont" id="res">A soma dos primeiros
  <input id="cont" type="number" name="num" min="0" max="100000000">multiplos de
  <input id="mul1" type="number" name="num" min="1" max="1000">e
  <input id="mul2" type="number" name="num" min="1" max="1000">é:</p>
<input type="button" value="Calcular" id="calcmult">
```

Comment: Não, este trecho acaba fazendo o mesmo que o meu codigo já faz =/

Answer (score 0):

Simples, porque você está sempre lendo o html atual usando `pad.innerHTML`. Você teria que guardar o valor *do html* no início, e não a referência do elemento:

```
var pad = document.getElementById("res").innerHTML;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a62bcyaf/2/)**</kbd>

Mas eu não recomendo essa prática. Porque não usar um elemento ao final da mensagem para exibir o valor? Exemplo:

```
... é: <span id="resultado"></span>
```

E então, ao final do script:

```
x = document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = y;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a62bcyaf/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: A versão do inner deu NaN e.e, mas eu sei q podia fazer isso criando um span, mas eu queria mesmo tentar no mesmo html. hm

Comment: @AlexandreGomes deve ter faltado o `y.toString();` na hora de concatenar. Dá uma olhada na linha 22 da primeira demo.